# Как привязать вызов меню через ID элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

ребят) Нашёл интересный вариант красивого кругового меню.

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/CreativePunch/details/lAHiu)

я планирую применить данное меню к новостям. Как сделать так, чтобы каждое меню вызывалось отдельно для каждой новости?

p.s. Есть тэг, который можно прописать в html и благодаря ему я могу вывести id для каждой новости отдельно) я так понимаю, нужно переделать копать в сторону querySelector

код

### html

```
<!-- Demo by http://creative-punch.net -->

<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
  </div>

  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>

<h1 class="author">Demo by <a href="http://creative-punch.net" target="_blank">Creative Punch</h1>
```

### css

```
/* Demo by http://creative-punch.net */

@import "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

body {
  background: #39D;
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #dde;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

/* Author stuff */
h1.author {
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.author a {
  color: #348;
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1.author a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}
```

### js

```
// Demo by http://creative-punch.net

var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

пример

[image: пример как всё это выглядит]

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы каждое меню вызывалось отдельно для каждой новости? - не понял о чем речь. Можете привести пример?

Comment: @adudnik.ru в общем, если сейчас использовать два одинаковых меню, то работать будет только одно из них, то, что первое. хотелось бы привязать их к id, дабы сделать их вызов отдельно друг от друга. меню 1 -нажимаю, появляется меню 1. меню 2 -нажимаю, появляется меню 2.

Comment: @adudnik.ru добавил иллюстрацию в топик)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вот так:

Просто замените JS на мой из примера, а остальную разметку вставляйте сколько угодно раз.

```js
var circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

circles.forEach(function(elem){
let items = elem.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}
});

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-button');
buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();    
   this.parentElement.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";
body {
  background: #39D;
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #dde;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

/* Author stuff */
h1.author {
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.author a {
  color: #348;
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1.author a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}
js
```

```html
<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
  </div> 
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
  </div> 
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
  </div> 
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! ^^